# How can I create an virtual USB printer on Mac?

Tags: virtual-machine, printer

I want to try to capture USB printer traffic, but I do not have a printer at home.

Is there any way I can create a virtual USB printer on Mac? I only know how to create a virtual network printer.

Comment: You're literally in need of capturing the data traffic… not just as a way of postponing printing until you have access to a printer?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. Not just postpone. I need to capture the traffic.

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure we weren't looking at an XY problem, solved by 'save to PDF' ;)  I'm afraid I have no clue how to achieve this, but I wish you luck.

Comment: Have you searched for virtual printers that work in Mac?